# add some jQuery to a Text Area to adjust height of it

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an asp textbox and label which is rendering as a text area:

```
<div class="control">
<asp:TextBox  runat="server" Rows="2"  ID="TextBox1"  Width="80%"   EnableViewState="false" ViewStateMode="Disabled" CssClass="textboxBootstrapCss" TextMode="MultiLine"   />
<asp:Label runat="server"  ID="Label1" Visible="false" ViewStateMode="Disabled" EnableViewState="false"  AssociatedControlID="TextBox1"  />
</div>
```

but i want to add some jquery to allow it to add `resize:both;` which will allow the text area's size to be changed from the user in the bottom right corner of the text area, as it does not work in IE i am using jquery to do it instead of css

here is my jquery:

```
 $(function () {
        $("textArea").resizable();
    });
```

Comment: do you have an Id that is "textArea"? it looks like it's called "TextBox1"?

Comment: as i am dropping that control onto my aspx, it renders as whatever i set it as in the aspx so that isnt the permanent ID.The page then renders as a <textarea>..  should the jquery method not find any text areas and make them sizeable?

Comment: <textareas> are already resizable, though?

Comment: they are, but not in IE .. only in chrome

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know if it works!

```
 $(function() {
     $( "#resizable" ).resizable({
containment: "#control"
});
     $( "#TextBox1" ).draggable({containment: "#control"});
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! but unfortunately it does not work, as i have used the control many times in the outside code where it references the textbox1 in your function wont work im afraid as when it renders its no longer called textbox1

Comment: Ok I think this guy was having the same problem so try looking at this.https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/655069/dragable-textbox-and-placeholder-within-that-textb